# MVC3 jQuery cancel validation via addClass not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.Net MVC3 with jQuery unobtrusive client-side validation. I need to bypass validation on my Cancel buttons. I can use the class=cancel technique and it works well. For example:

```
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Cancel" class="cancel" />
```

However, I have at least 100 of these buttons across the application. Rather than editing them all, I'd like to add that class using jQuery. For example:

```
$("input[type='submit'][name='SubmitButton'][value='Cancel']").addClass("cancel");
```

This adds the class just fine, and I can see it using Developer Tools, however, it doesn't prevent client-side validation. So, explicitly adding the class works, but dynamically adding the class fails. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: It looks like the answer could have been

    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse

But, most people are saying that they can't get the function to work. I'm reverting to hardcoding the class name until I can get this working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're adding the class in the browser after the page is already loaded, so the buttons aren't getting the event handler they need because they only get the class after the handler is assigned to that class. Maybe if you put the line of jQuery you have above before the validation script that might fix it.